# How to use a lambda function to sort a dictionary with a nested list?

Tags: python, function, sorting, dictionary

I've been trying to sort a dictionary based on largest to lowest values. The dictionary is structured like this:

```
testing = {"third":[1,89],"first":[5,46],"second":[3,59]}
```

The issue I'm coming across is that I'm not entirely sure as to how I can sort this based on the second listed value, so I want to sort it based on 89, 46 and 59. Not the first 1,5,3.

The method I was currently using is:

```
print(sorted(testing,key=lambda x:x[1][-1]))
```

Which is sorting the dictionary, but not in the way I'm trying to get it to. Where second is being sorted for the first value.

I'm sure there's a way to do this, I'm just not sure how to approach this lambda function. Any guidance would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(testing.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])`?

output:

```
[('first', [5, 46]), ('second', [3, 59]), ('third', [1, 89])]
```

Comment: I tried that, it would give a string index out of range error.


Edit: WHOOPS. I misread it, I didn't read that you used .items() on the dictionary. Now that works, thank you so much.